# Birt reports, how to add a workorder (WONUM) on the footer of a master page?

Tags: birt

Is there a way to add a element from the scripted dataset (WONUM) on the bottom of Master page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

open your masterpage, drag and drop your value from your data-set into the footer of your masterpage. The footer of the Masterpage can only contain one element. If you want to display multiple values, create a Grid in the footer (or any other container element) and add the values to this item.